deploy safe global 4337 on Arbitrum Sepolia
I found that Safe Global 4337 module is deployed on Arbitrum Sepolia (and BSC testnet). And the smartcontracts are here for v1.4.1.
However when I tried safe4337Pack and these docs I receveid an error that only contracts up to version v1.1.1 are supported.
How do I go on lower level and use the set of contract deployed for 1.4.1 from typescript with SDK. All I need is to a 4337 Smart Wallet with Safe Global. I would also like to see how can I use it with and without Paymaster... With ZeroDev I did not figure yet.

Not sure I fully understand the question. Do you want to use contracts other than v1.4.1 with 4337? If so, that's not possible.
If you'd like a guide on how to deploy a v1.4.1 Safe using the SDK and TypeScript, this guide might be of help to you.
